# search dynamically PHP MYSQL PDO

Tags: php, mysql

I have a form with 3 select boxes: age,room,type.

```
<form action="results.php" method="get">
<div class="form-group">
<select name="age">
     <option value>Any</option>
     <option value="1">15</option>
     <option value="2">25</option>
     <option value="3">30</option>
     <option value="4">40</option>
   </select>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<select name="room">
     <option value>Any</option>
     <option value="1">1</option>
     <option value="2">2</option>
   </select>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<select name="type">
     <option value>Any</option>
     <option value="1">Personal</option>
     <option value="2">Business</option>
   </select>
</div>
</form>
```

What i am trying to do with PDO is to make a small search. 
If all variables are empty then my condition is:

```
$search = $db->query("SELECT * FROM table");
```

If 1 of them (as example the age) is not empty then i have:

```
 if(!empty($_GET['age'])){
$age = $_GET['age'];
$search = $db->query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE age = '$age'");
}
```

Now, if 2 of them are npt empty i have:

```
if(!empty($_GET['age']) && !empty($GET['room'])){
    $age = $_GET['age'];
$room = $_GET['room'];
    $search = $db->query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE age = '$age' AND room = '$room'");
    }
```

In order to avoid all possible search combinations, how can i make a search with the term if is not empty. I had made one in the past:

```
if(!empty($age)){
$where = "WHERE age = '$age'";
}

if(!empty($room)){
$where .= "and room = '$room'";
}

$query = "SELECT * FROM table $where";
```

How can i make it happen with PDO?? :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd do something like this:

```
$param = array();
$query = 'SELECT ... FROM t WHERE 1=1';

if(!empty($_GET['age'])){
  $param['age'] = $_GET['age'];
  $query .= ' AND t.age = :age';
}

if(!empty($_GET['room'])){
  $param['room'] = $_GET['room'];
  $query .= ' AND t.room = :room';
}

if(!empty($_GET['type'])){
  $param['type'] = $_GET['type'];
  $query .= ' AND t.type = :type';
}

$dbh->prepare($query)->execute($param);
```

You might want to separate out the `prepare` and the `execute`. Check the return from the `prepare` before you try calling `execute`. Or, configure PDO can throw an exception when an error occurs, e.g.

```
 $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```

Comment: it works fine..is it safe from SQL Injection attacks?

Comment: Yes. Using a *prepared statement* with *bind placeholders* is the normative pattern to avoid SQL Injection vulnerabilities. Your code is still dependent on the patterns used by the PDO functions. PDO can use real server side prepared statements, but it can also "emulate" prepared statements. In emulation mode, PDO is responsible for properly escaping the values that get included in the SQL text. Your code is only as vulnerable as the PDO functions are. For added protection, your code could perform additional "whitelist" check of the supplied values, rejecting invalid values.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to make a query builder of some kind. You will also want to use prepared statements, rather than directly injecting user-provided input into the sql query. That might look something like this:

```
<?php

$search = [
    'age' => 42,
    'room' => 'Millyway',
];

$criteria = [];
$params = [];

foreach($search as $field => $value) {
    $criteria[] = "$field = :$field";
    $params[$field] = $value;
}

$where = ($criteria ? ('WHERE ' . implode(' AND ', $criteria)) : '');

$query = "SELECT * FROM tablename $where";
$stmt = $db->prepare($query);
$stmt->execute($params);

while($obj = $stmt->fetchObject()) {
    // iterate over your result set
}
```

Given search terms as key-values in `$search` (which can be any column and value in the table, and will need to be populated from wherever those values come from), this code will build `$criteria`, a set of `WHERE` clause fragments (using a parameterized sql parameter name, rather than injecting the value directly), and `$params`, the list of parameters to be passed into the (upcoming) prepared statement.

It then builds the full `WHERE` clause in `$where`, by either combining all of the `$criteria` that were built, or returning an empty string. This is then added directly into the query, and the query is executed using the parameters array that was built up. You then iterate over the result set like any other PDO query.

Among others, the main benefit of using parameterized SQL over injecting variables directly is that it protects you from SQL Injection attacks.

Note that there are many ways this code could be improved. You could easily put it in a function; add complexity to allow for different types of comparisons (e.g. `<>` or `LIKE`); even use it as the basis for a more complicated query builder that allows more complicated logic such as `((age = :age AND room = :room1) OR (room = :room2))`; and so on. What you do is up to the needs of your application.

Comment: i used $search = [ 'age' => $age, 'room' => $room]; but it shows me as result all the rows of my database table..what i am doing wrong? i have to change something else?

Comment: My bad, typo in the foreach. Should have been `$search`, not `$criteria`. Answer updated.

Comment: maybe another mistake? it shows me blank page now.. :/

Comment: The variable name in the foreach was the only thing I changed. If it was giving you results before, and you're getting an error (or nothing) now, there's probably an error somewhere else.